# How can i write a c# loop to calculate Tution increase by 2% each year for the next 5 years

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

the tuition for a full-time student is $12000 per year. It has been announced that the tuition will increase by 2% each year for the next 5 years.How can i write a c# loop to calculate Tution increase by 2% each year for the next 5 years

My code thus far is..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string display;         
        double initialfee = 12000.00;
        double increase,newfee;
        double rate = 0.02;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
        {
            increase = initialfee * rate * year;
            newfee = increase + initialfee;


            display = "year " + year.ToString() + ": " + "  Amount " + "$" + newfee;

            listBox1.Items.Add(display);
```

Comment: is the increase compound or not? i.e. is the increase always 2% of "initialfee", or is it that each is year the increase is 2% of "newfee". In other words, what is the denominator?

Comment: use `newfee` to calculate the `increase` instead of always the `initalfee` again. But be sure to initialize `newfee` correctly.

Comment: P.S. Why are you multiplying by the year as well? This isn't a C# problem, it's a basic maths problem.

Comment: A 2% increase is a multiplication by 1.02

Comment: worked perfectly..thank you

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to multiply by year.
Try this

```
string display;         
double initialfee = 12000.00;
double increase=0,newfee;
double rate = 0.02;


for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
{
    if(year>1)
    {
        increase = initialfee * rate;
    }

    initialfee = increase + initialfee;


    display = "year " + year.ToString() + ": " + "  Amount " + "$" + initialfee;
    Console.WriteLine(display);

}
```

Output:

```
year 1:   Amount $12000
year 2:   Amount $12240
year 3:   Amount $12484.8
year 4:   Amount $12734.496
year 5:   Amount $12989.18592
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution to calculate.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string display;         
    double initialfee = 12000.00;
    double increase,newfee;
    double rate = 0.02;
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
    {
       newfee = initialfee + (initialfee * 2/100 * year);
       display = "year " + year.ToString() + ": " + "  Amount " + "$" + newfee;
    }
}
```

this calculates like 2% first year, 4% next year and so on.

**if 2% Compound increase each year is what is required**, then,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string display;         
    double initialfee = 12000.00;
    double increase,newfee;
    double rate = 0.02;
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
    {
      if(year == 1)
          newfee = initialfee;
      else
          newfee = newfee + (newfee * 2 / 100);

      display = "year " + year.ToString() + ": " + "  Amount " + "$" + newfee;
    }
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* solution:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Please, see separation:

// Model: here we define condition

// initial conditions  
double initialfee = 12000.00;
double rate = 0.02;
int years = 5;

// Business logic: here we obtain data

// please, notice formatting (here is C# 6.0 string interpolation) 
// which is easier to read and maintain then contructing string from chunks added.
var data = Enumerable
  .Range(1, years)
  .Select(year => $"Year {year}: Amount: {Math.Pow(1.0 + rate, year - 1) * initialfee:f2}")
  .ToArray();

// Representation: UI representation

// Add items in one go to prevent redrawing and blinking
listBox1.Items.AddRange(data);
```

Outcome is

```
Year 1: Amount: 12000.00
Year 2: Amount: 12240.00
Year 3: Amount: 12484.80
Year 4: Amount: 12734.50
Year 5: Amount: 12989.19
```

I know, you're looking for a loop solution, but in Real World we usually prefer working with *data queries*.